# Check for broken formula hyperlinks for local files (Excel - VBA)

Tags: excel, hyperlink, automation, vba

An automatic hyperlink is created in a table once the user enters a number in another column

The formula is as following:

```
HYPERLINK(Config!$D$2 & Config!$C$2 & "-MECH-" & TEXT([@Serial],"000") & "\" & id_wCode & "-" & Config!$C$2 & "-MECH-" & TEXT([@Serial],"000") & "-" & TEXT([@[Rev.]],"00") & FileExt,"Open")
```

The cell references in the formula contains the path for a pre-defined folder system structure and naming pattern for both the files and folders.

> id_wCode = is a constant number that is defined for each workbook
>
> FileExt = ".pdf"

The links are working fine but I need to tell the user "File Not Found" if the file isn't placed yet in the folder and/or not following the naming pattern.

Comment: Would the IFERROR() function work for you?

Comment: Care to Illustrate more ?

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(3/0, "Faulty formula")` in any cell. `3/0` will produce a division by zero error. Therefore this formula will return "Faulty formula". I wonder if your formula would throw an error if the file wasn't found. If so, IFERROR() might catch it and return "File not found".

Comment: No problem with the formula or the link, what I am asking for is a way to tell if the file exists or not. In case the file exist the link works perfectly but if the file is not in place the link (formula) will pop-up a message box telling "Cannot open the specified file" that what I need to tell the user without having him to click on the hyperlink to know if the file is there or not.

Comment: I understand that. Does your formula throw an error if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: No, it don't if by error you mean (#Value,#Ref,#Name, ... etc) the one that you get in cells when your formula contains errors but this one is a hyperlink meaning I get an error message box that the file doesn't exist; this kind of error can't be handled with the `IFERROR` formula.

Comment: In that case you would need VBA to make that check, and once you start using VBA you should let VBA set the hyperlink.